# "Can't find of appInfo for ..." when trying to deploy web service to TomEE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-tomee

I have a very simple project I've created for training purposes. Its a RESTful webservice and I've created a client using js,css and html. I'm trying to deploy the service to TomEE. This is the error I get when trying to deploy:

[image: Screenshot on my part of my idea]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have same problem. Have you solve this already?

Answer (score 1):

Just had this issue. I had a `META-INF/context.xml` with an empty path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path=""/>
```

Either deleting the file or setting a path (a relative URI, e.g. "/appname") both worked.

Answer (score 0):

it should be linked to the name of the artifact or something like it, maybe open an Idea issue